# JSLint doesn't like var

Tags: javascript, jslint

I was probing my code for errors with JSLint and so far I managed to fix all bugs except the problem when my global application variable is undefined.

I was using this code before JSlint which worked properly:

```
var APP = APP || (function {
    return {
        init: function () {

        }
    };
}(window.document));
```

then I would call

```
APP.init();
```

to initialize. But JSlint doesn't like global variables so I changed my code to this:

```
(function (global){
    var APP = {
        init: function () {

        }
    };
    return APP;
}(window.document));
```

This code passes the JSLint test with no problem, but then
when I call APP.init(); it says that APP is used before it was defined, which is true.
What would you recommend so that I don't use global variables but still create my application object, while my code passes JSlint test?

Comment: In your rewritten version, `APP` is a local variable. If you try to use it outside that function, you'll get an error.

Comment: *then when I call APP.init();* — You don't call that function in the code you've shared, so its difficult to tell what JSLint is complaining about.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid global variables, EVERYTHING has to be within that `function(global)` function, including `APP.init()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First code**

In your original code, the actual error you would have gotten was

```
 #1 'APP' used out of scope.
    var APP = APP || (function() { // Line 1, Pos 11
```

It is not because JSLint hates global variables, but because *it doesn't like the variable being assigned to it is defined in the same `var` statement.*

Changing your code to use a different variable name would fix this problem

```
var app = APP || (function() {...}(..));
```

but then, one would expect that `APP` is already defined in the current scope. Otherwise you will get

```
 #1 'APP' was used before it was defined.
```

**Second code**

It doesn't work because, `APP` is visible only inside the function object you created. It is not visible anywhere outside it. Since you want to define `APP` in the global scope, you just have to attach it to the `window` object, like this

```
(function(global) {
    global.APP = {
        init: function() {

        }
    };
}(window));
```

Then

```
APP.init()
```

will work fine.

Instead of going through all these, you can straight away define `APP` like this

```
window.APP = {
    init: function () {
        "use strict";
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Well the idea holds water thought JSLint still complains that APP is used before it was undefined. :) I tried my app with the new script and yes it works.

Comment: @Vlad Which suggested change did you use?

Comment: the second one, with global.APP = { };

Comment: @Vlad Hmmm, did you try `window.APP` approach? It seems very simple and neat to me

Comment: @Vlad Sorry, I meant the last approach I suggested in the answer.

Comment: I had this as a last part of my script window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {'use strict';
    APP.init({"event": event});
    }); This was causing the APP is not defined error. But yes now APP is accessible trough window.

Comment: `but because it doesn't like the variable being assigned to it is defined in the same var statement.` The "why": If this was literally your code, `var APP` means you're declaring `APP` *now* and *know* it's not initialized. You're "really" implicitly calling the `APP` object/property on the global object - `window.APP`. JSLint says "Make your global call explicit" (see [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28026893/1028230)). "[Don't use] idioms that are hard to distinguish from obvious errors," which requires explicit `window` use here ([Crockford](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html)).

Answer (score 1):

```
    (function (global){
    var APP = {
        init: function () {

        }
    };
    return APP;
}(window.document));
```

the above creates a scope/closure, so that only code inside your anonymous function can access the APP variable. JSHint has settings so you can set acceptable globals (such as jquery etc), I'd add `APP` to that and if the rest pass you know you only have that one variable/module as global. If you are using any 3rd party libs chances are you already have several global vars anyway

Comment: Yes, my intentions were that I use only one global variable and no other third party libraries, so yes the code I have is pure JS code written from scratch. I'll try JSHint, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Before you [give up on JSLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025999/jslint-doesnt-like-var#comment44437801_28026148), know that it doesn't mind globals at all; it just wants you to declare them with a special format so that others reading your code know exactly what's going on.

The only "trick" here is if there's a chance your global `APP` isn't initialized yet and you really need to check for its "truthiness", as you do with `APP = APP || (function...`. Then you *do* need to use the `window` (or whatever your global object is -- it's different if you use Node, for example) prefix trick.

Here's how:

```
/*jslint white:true, sloppy:true, browser:true */
/*global APP */

window.APP = window.APP || (function () {
    return {
        init: function () {
            window.alert('JSLint doesn\'t like empty blocks');
        }
    };
}(window.document));


APP.init();
```

And JSLint is happy!

I'm not against JSHint in theory, but that same flexibility that allows you to set all sorts of extra settings also tends to erode conformity, which is largely what I find the best benefit of a code linter to be. Give both a good, solid run, and see which you like best!